# Google OAuth 2.0 for WPF and ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api, google-oauth

Trying to use Google authentication for `WPF` app and `ASP.NET WebAPI`.

Registered project in Google Cloud Console, got `Client Id` and `Client Secret` for Desktop type application.
In `WPF` app I was redirected to Google page, logged in, etc. and finally exchanged code for `access token`.

I tried to use this token to authorize in `WebAPI` app, but failed - `WepAPI` app returns `html` text of google login page.

`WPF` app request:

```cs
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
     string str = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7072/Controller/id?id=1");
```

and `str` contained `html` page

`WebAPI` `Program.cs`:

```cs
     builder.Services
         .AddAuthentication()
         .AddGoogle(options =>
         {
             options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
             options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
         });

     // --- other code ---
     app.UseAuthorization();
     app.UseAuthentication();
```

So, there are 2 questions:

1. Is assess token obtained in `WPF` app valid for `WebAPI` app?
2. What is the right way to authentifacate user in desktop app to access services after?